# ios5 GM upgrade went bad...how to save my device?

Tags: upgrade, ios5

I have tried to follow the upgrade to iOS5 process...
but didn't realize that my device must be registered in iOS developer program.

I have registered the apple id in the program (after i upgraded the device) - but now when i load the device - it says it is unable to activate my device because my device is not registered in the ios developer program.

How should i resolve this issue? We have a developer license - and we have paid the enrollment fee to apple.

I need to figure out how to complete the upgrade to ios5 or to rollback the device to 4.3 in order to restore it's functionality.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to re-install the ios5 Beta GM on the device.
it worked like a charm.

it turns out that rollback from 5 backward is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Restore it using a previously downloaded iOS image in xCode Organizer. If you don't have an image, you can download them off Apple's Developer portal.